# ElasticSearch Bulk Delete by id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire, curb

I'm attempting to do a bulk delete by ids and it appears to be not working. When I run my test suite and try via the Rails console, it seems to work OK. However, I'm running into occurrences where there are documents that simply don't get removed. The response however, indicates it was successful.

Using `tire` 0.5.8, `curb` 0.8.4, ElasticSearch 0.90.2.

```
query = Tire::Search::Search.new do
  query do
    filtered do
      query { all }
      filter(:terms, _id: ids_array)
    end
  end
end

Curl::Easy.http_delete("#{index.url}/_query?source=#{Tire::Utils.escape(query.to_hash[:query].to_json)}") do |curb|
  curb.http_auth_types = :basic
  curb.username = ENV["ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME"]
  curb.password = ENV["ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD"]
end
```

The model mapping looks like:

```
tire.settings ElasticSearchAnalysis do
  mapping _all: { enabled: false } do
    indexes :id, type: "integer"
  end
end
```

Sample HTTP DELETE:

```
DELETE /production_shifts/_query?source=%7B%22filtered%22%3A%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%22match_all%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%22filter%22%3A%7B%22and%22%3A%5B%7B%22terms%22%3A%7B%22_id%22%3A%5B587965789%2C587965791%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D%7D
```

When unescaped, the query looks like:

```
{\"filtered\":{\"query\":{\"match_all\":{}},\"filter\":{\"and\":[{\"terms\":{\"_id\":[587965789,587965791}}]}}}
```

Comment: In the past I've had problems with deleting objects from elasticsearch but the problem was with ES and not Tire.

Comment: What does your failing test look like? Do you add documents and then immediately delete them?

Comment: Can you answer the questions of the people or at least accept some answer? It would be useful for other users. Or if you have solved it yourself just add the solution as answer and accept the same. You can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

That 'and' in the json query looks wrong. Nothing is going to match that query.

In any case, try the same query with a get to see what you get back.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a filtered query there?

You have indexed the id field as id not _id...
The below query should work for sure, this is a tested query.

You can just use this,

```
query = Tire.search do |search|
        search.query { |q| q.terms :id, ids_array }
      end
```

Reference: https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/309